# Table: Caption is centered but table itself not

Tags: horizontal-alignment, floats, captions

I have another problem with a table in my document. The following code centers the caption but not the table itself. Any hints why?

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (table) [inner sep=0pt] {
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
  \textbf{Class} & \textbf{Package} & \textbf{Project} \\
\hline
FANIN & CALLS & CALLS\\
FANOUT & NOM & AHH\\
CALLS & NOP & ANDC\\
HIT (only root classes) & & NOC\\
NDC & & NOP\\
NOA & & \\
NOM & & \\
NOPAR & & \\
\end{tabular}
};
\draw [rounded corners=.5em] (table.north west) rectangle (table.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Metrics provided by the webservice}
\label{tbl:web_service_metrics}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you haven't used `\centering` (for example) to center the `tikzpicture` environment containing your table, so the table won't be centered; on the other hand, the standard `\caption` command centers its argument if it fits in one line. Simply add a `\centering` command right after `\begin{table}[htbp]`